# Rails ActiveStorage images disappears

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Active Storage image attachments disappears after some couple of minutes in production environment. I am able to upload the images, it appears for some minutes then disappears.

In local it says 'Image cannot be displayed because it contains error' and in Google Storage it says like 'The provided token has expired'.

I am using rail 5.2.3 and Ruby 2.6.0.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with your Google Storage configuration. If you are able to see during few minutes your image in production it's because there is a cache, I know Heroku work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're using a temporary url, try using `url_for` helper, it should give you a public permanent url.

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#linking-to-files

Or `rails_blob_url` for downloading and `rails_representation_url` for attachment variants.